# shell script program run at 2 line only after that line will automatically skipped

Tags: shell

I have to make for to easy to connect mysql data with using the lampstack application ubuntu. But my script has been work but not fully .

It only run till 2nd line. The rest of the script is skipped.

Here is my script.

```
cd  '/usr/software/lampstack-5.4.38-0'
./use_lampstack
echo $PATH
cd 'mysql/bin'
mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the file and check what is breaking:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
cd '/usr/software/lampstack-5.4.38-0'
./use_lampstack
echo $PATH
cd'mysql/bin'
mysql -u root -p
```

My guess is that use_lampstack is just keeping the script from finishing.

If `use_lampstack` blocks execution, change that line to `./use_lampstack &` so that it can run in the background.

Comment: The `-x` option looks a nice idea. But I am not sure if wishes to run `use_lampstack` in background.  The op should probably shed some light on what `use_lampstack` is.